# What tax documents do I need to prove 529 rollover?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, rollover, 529-plan

I rolled over 529 from one institution to another. The distributing institution issued a 1099-Q. I need a matching document showing that I contributed the funds to the new institution. Does this form have a specific name? Can I just provide the IRS with a statement from the new institution?

Comment: Was the rollover done in 2020 or 2021? What codes/boxes are on the 1099-Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Publication 970](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p970.pdf) (PDF), page 63, it seems that you do not need a "matching document":

> An amount is rolled over if it's paid to an ABLE account or another
> QTP within 60 days after the date of the distribution.
>
> Note. Under COVID-19 emergency relief, the student could roll over
> these amounts by July 15, 2020, if the 60-day period ends on or after
> April 1, 2020, and before July 15, 2020.
>
> Don't report qualifying rollovers (those that meet the above criteria)
> anywhere on Form 1040, 1040-SR, or 1040-NR. These aren't taxable
> distributions.